# Python write as a file, unknown format

Tags: python, file, output

So here's a small snippet of a file opened in python. But I'm not sure what kind of formatting this is. Doesn't look like binary. How do I write this back out into a file?

```
hDuwHkAbG9hZGVyX21jAEAAiQYJHgBpAEAQAHBAAIkGCR4AaQBAEACsQACJBgkeAGkAQBAA5EAAiQYJHgBpAEAQARxAAIkGCR4AaQBAEAFUQACJBgkeAGkAQBABkEAAiQYJHgBpAEAQAchAAIkGCR4AaQBAEAIAQACJBgkeAGkAQBACOEAAiQYJHgBpAEAQAnBAAIkGCR4AaQBAEAKsQACJBgkeAGkAQ
```

Comment: why can't you just write it back out as-is?

Comment: It looks like base64-encoded something.  The structure inside seems to contain a list of other structures, each 13 bytes long.  As to what is contained within, your guess is as good as (or better than) mine.

Comment: So basically, I'm working with a SWF file, I want to be able to write it back out as a SWF file. Not sure how to do it :\

Comment: Looks like a SHA-224 hash (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2). If so; it's one-way (like md5) so it can't be guessed except you use brute force. Is it a license or authentication file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fragment of a [base-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded binary file of some sort. Unfortunately, it hasn't been cut at a byte boundary; however, when I insert a letter at the front, the decoded version looks like this:

```
ÆîÀy�loader_mc�@�   �i�@�p@�    �i�@�¬@�    �i�@�ä@�    �i�@@�  �i�@T@� �i�@@�  �i�@È@� �i�@�@� �i�@8@� �i�@p@� �i�@¬@� �i�
```

You can see some clear meaningful ASCII in there. However, what the binary data represents is anyone's guess.

If you just need to decode it into the above binary format, use the [`base64`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) module.

Comment: If it is an SWF file like he says, it's probably hashed to be source protected, or password-locked. It has the precise structure of an SHA-2 224-bit digest hash.